# how to make sure an arraylist doesn't return null?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a bunch of lists and for the search of those lists i add all of the lists data to a `arrayList` but im living in Iran and my gov disable our access to twitch at nights and i add the twitch data to my `arrayList` too but when we dont have access the search `recyclerView` with arrayList will be null this is my Twitch code

```
`private void getTwitch(String twitchUrl, final ArrayList lists) {
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, twitchUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray stream = response.getJSONArray("streams");
                    Log.i("stream",stream.toString());
                    TwitchApiParser parser = new TwitchApiParser();
                    ArrayList items= parser.ParseTwitch(stream,SearchActivity.this,200,200);
                    for (int i =0;i<items.size();i++){
                        lists.add(items.get(i));
                    }

                    searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this,lists,SearchActivity.this);
                    recyclerSearch.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SearchActivity.this));
                    recyclerSearch.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this,lists,SearchActivity.this);
                recyclerSearch.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SearchActivity.this));
                recyclerSearch.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                Log.e(error.toString(),"search");
            }
        });
        RequestQueue quew = Volley.newRequestQueue(SearchActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
        quew.add(request);

    }`
```

when we dont have access the app will crash for null pointer error please tell me how can i do it for nights(without twitch) and also i dont know when the access will be disabled.

Comment: What response you get when twitch server is disabled?

Comment: So `items` is null? How about you simply put an `if (items != null) {...}` around your for loop.

Comment: @Ankur_009 on volley error i will get Timeout

Comment: @mkasberg when i cant reach twitch server i will get error

Comment: Is `items` null so your loop throws the NPE or does `ParseTwitch` throw the NPE itself?

Comment: @csmckelvey i dont have response so it will go on ErrorResposnse im using Volley

Comment: If you can't tell us where exactly the NPE comes from then we can't really help you.

Comment: @csmckelvey NPE comes from my recyclerView and i use this ArrayList for recyclerView adapter

Comment: `ArrayList<> arr = parser.....; if(arr.isEmpty()) return Collections.list(); return arr;`

Answer (score 1):

Move your Twitch api call into this method

```
public ArrayList getDataFromTwitch(JSONArray stream) {
    TwitchApiParser parser = new TwitchApiParser();
    ArrayList items = parser.ParseTwitch(stream,SearchActivity.this,200,200);

    if (items == null) {
        return new ArrayList();
    }
    return items;
}
```

Then you can simply call

```
ArrayList items = getDataFromTwitch(stream);
```

Here you can safely use it now

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method like this :

```
`private void getTwitch(String twitchUrl, final ArrayList lists) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, twitchUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONArray stream = response.getJSONArray("streams");
                Log.i("stream",stream.toString());
                TwitchApiParser parser = new TwitchApiParser();
                ArrayList items= parser.ParseTwitch(stream,SearchActivity.this,200,200);
                if(items.isEmpty()) {
                    items = Collections.emptyList();
                } else {
                    lists.forEach(items::add);
                }

                searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this,lists,SearchActivity.this);
                recyclerSearch.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SearchActivity.this));
                recyclerSearch.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this,lists,SearchActivity.this);
            recyclerSearch.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SearchActivity.this));
            recyclerSearch.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
            Log.e(error.toString(),"search");
        }
    });
    RequestQueue quew = Volley.newRequestQueue(SearchActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
    quew.add(request);

}`
```